# How does one know how to read 堪える? Is it 「こたえる」、「こらえる」 or 「たえる」?

Tags: nuances, kanji, readings

The verb `堪える` has three different readings: `こたえる`, `こらえる`, and `たえる`, and as far as I can tell they all mean "to bear, to endure, to put up with", with slight variations. Is there a way to tell which reading is correct in any given instance? Is it nuanced or a regional variance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kanjigen only lists `堪{た}える` and Kanjidic lists that reading first, so I'm guessing it would normally use that reading. Looking at the [Goo thesaurus](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/thsrs/4289/m0u/%E3%81%93%E3%82%89/), `こらえる` seems to be often written with Hiragana.

`こらえる` also has the additional meanings of "refrain, repress, keep back". As fefe has noted, it's normally `～をこらえる` and `～に堪{た}える` as the former generally refers to holding back feelings from within whereas the latter generally refers to enduring pressure etc from outside. `こらえる` seems to take the meaning of "endure, stand" when written as `～はこらえられない` and `～はこらえて` et al.

It may be read as `堪{こた}える` in some contexts, but I think that reading is usually only used in e.g. `踏{ふ}み堪{こた}える` and `持{も}ち堪{こた}える`.

Answer (score 4):

Comparing the goo explanation for [こらえる](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/82575/m0u/%E3%81%93%E3%82%89%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B/) [たえる](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/135060/m0u/) and [こたえる](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/79630/m0u/%E3%81%93%E3%81%9F%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B/), we can see that:

堪{こら}える is usually used with を: 痛みを[堪]{こら}える 
堪{た}える is usually used with に: 暑さに[堪]{た}える 
堪{こた}える is often used to form compound words: 踏み[堪]{こた}える

And for `堪`, `堪{た}える` is the only kun reading listed in 常用漢字, so you may see the other two be written in kana more.

Comment: I wish I could check two answers, or combine them, I +1'd this one :)